# Mapping from openstack cli to REST API

Tags: openstack

Is there a mapping of which REST APIs the openstack-cli uses for the various requests?  Obviously, in all cases (?) it will use keystone to get a token and then it will go on and use the REST APIs of the various components to perform the request.  It would be nice if which APIs -- or at least which component(s) -- the request was using.

I'm wanting this to debug a particular component.  Lets say I have an issue with Cinder.  Its not obvious to me which openstack CLI commands would use Cinder and which APIs.  It would be nice if I could look through a list and say "Oh!! 'openstack get foo bar deluxe' will exercise that particular API" (or a particular URI may be more accurate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is documentation for mapping openstackclient CLI to REST API. Typically a CLI could call more than one REST API to fetch the required information. Best resource for this mapping would be the source code itself. 
https://github.com/openstack/python-openstackclient

On the other hand, I think the REST API documentation of OpenStack is pretty exhaustive and detailed. You can access the REST API from https://developer.openstack.org/api-guide/quick-start/

Comment: Thanks.  The second reference is nice.  I had bumped into them individually but its nice that there is a page that collects them all.  The one nit is you have to look for "identity" instead of "keystone" for example.  Thanks again...